# How to get such an expandable layout?

Tags: android, android-cardview, expandablerecyclerview

Does anyone know how to get an expandable layout like the payment method and the in the link? I don't want it to be in a listview because I need such an expandable layout works for other things with different content. Or it could be in an expandable list view if items have different content can be fitted in. Thank you in advance!

http://chairnerd.seatgeek.com/images/autocomplete_checkout.gif

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution.

Put something like the following in your layout file

```
<com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/expandableLayout4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/expandableButton4"
            android:background="#ffcc80"
            android:padding="16dp"
            app:ael_duration="400"
            app:ael_expanded="false"
            app:ael_interpolator="accelerate"
            app:ael_orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="Things to put in the expandable layout" />
        </com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout>
```

Add to your build gradle file

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.6.0@aar'}
```

The way to set onClick listener for expanding the layout

```
public void expandableButton1(View view) {
    expandableLayout1 = (ExpandableRelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.expandableLayout1);
    expandableLayout1.toggle(); // toggle expand and collapse
}
```

More detail description: http://www.codeisall.com/android-expandable-layout/

Comment: jcenter() is closed so it's not working anymore, is there another library?